# Log the requests in FastAPI into specific file inside the project directory

Tags: python, logging, request, python-requests, fastapi

I am building an API for a dictionary on FastAPI python.
I am new at this framework, but I kinda like it, so I wanted to give it a try.
As part of the requirements, one of the requirements is to log every HTTP request into a specific file .log file inside my project, not in server side.

I tried using middleware, but I couldn't figure it out..
So if you guys have any ideas on how to do that, please help me since I cannot find so much about this topic.

So every request generated in my API enpdoints like mysite.com/words, I have to log this on a file,including a timestamp and some other information which is not important, because that's part of the details, but all I want is to be able to get every request and log them to a text file..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

i use a yaml config file in my project and it looks something like this to log everything from uvicorn:

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: no
    formatters:
        simple:
            format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    handlers:
        ...
        uvicorn:
            class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
            level: DEBUG
            formatter: simple
            when: D
            backupCount: 0
            filename: ./logs/uvicorn.log
    loggers:
        ...
        uvicorn:
            level: INFO
            handlers: [uvicorn]
            propagate: yes
            qualname: uvicorn
```

you could adapt this into code or just use it in a config file

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the native `logging` module in Python. For example:

```
#logger_config.py
import logging


def setup_logger(name) -> logging.Logger:
    FORMAT = "[%(name)s %(module)s:%(lineno)s]\n\t %(message)s \n"
    TIME_FORMAT = "%d.%m.%Y %I:%M:%S %p"

    logging.basicConfig(
        format=FORMAT, datefmt=TIME_FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG, filename="my-project-root/path/log-file-name.log"
    )

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    return logger


# in any file that import fn setup_logger from the above 'logger_config.py', you can set up local logger like:
local_logger = setup_logger(__name__)

local_logger.info(
    f"I am writing to file {FILENAME}. If that file did not exist, it would be automatically created. Here, you can change me to write about the call to a specific route function etc."
)
```